# How can I simplify this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
IF EXISTS(select 1 from TABLEA trn WITH(NOLOCK) 
          INNER JOIN TABLEB mst  
          ON trn.ID = mst.ID 
          Where trn.ID = 1 and trn.SeqNo=@SeqNo ) 
OR NOT EXISTS(select 1 from TABLEA trn WITH(NOLOCK) 
              INNER JOIN TABLEB mst  
              ON trn.ID = mst.ID 
              where trn.SeqNo=@SeqNo)
     BEGIN
     --Do something clever here
     END
     ELSE
     BEGIN
     --Throw custom error here
     END
```

I have this query to perform some operation if the value is null or satisfies the first condition else I have to throw some custom error message to the user.

Is there any other way i can do this or Can i simplify this query into further faster query.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN EXISTS(select 1 from TABLEA trn WITH(NOLOCK) 
                            INNER JOIN TABLEB mst ON trn.ID = mst.ID   
                            Where trn.ID = 1 and trn.SeqNo=@SeqNo) 
              OR 
              NOT EXISTS(select 1 from TABLEA trn WITH(NOLOCK) 
                                  INNER JOIN TABLEB mst ON trn.ID = mst.ID 
                                  where trn.SeqNo=@SeqNo)
        THEN 'EXISTS'
        ELSE 'NOT EXISTS'
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below query helps:

```
select case when trn.ID = 1 then 'EXISTS' else 'NOT EXISTS' END as status
from TABLEA trn WITH(NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN TABLEB mst 
ON trn.ID = mst.ID   
Where trn.SeqNo=@SeqNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 IF EXISTS(select 1 from TABLEA trn WITH(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN TABLEB mst
   ON trn.ID = mst.ID 
   Where (trn.ID = 1 and trn.SeqNo=@SeqNo) OR trn.SeqNo<>@SeqNo)
 BEGIN
  Select 'Exists'
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
  Select 'Not Exists'
 END
```